# Parallel/Series Resistors Voltage measurement

Tags: resistors, resistance, voltage-divider, parallel, voltage-measurement

[image]

I want to know the value of the resistors here. There are three conditions in this picture. Its getting really hard to fulfil the correct resistor values. Thats why i decided to post it here

Comment: What have you tried so far? Does the binary arrangement suggest any strategy?

Comment: I tried with some linear combinations like 1k, 2k, 3k values but it seems like there are always one or two measurements with less than 0.25V difference

Comment: Think about it from first principles, don't just blindly try values until you get something that works.

Comment: Hint: You might have to pay attention carefully to the wording of the question under requirements.

Comment: yes i tried but still no success

Comment: can you help me finding the values?

Comment: Maybe if you try parallel resistance multiple of 2 ie R,2R,4R

Comment: did not work. Main issue is there should always be 0.25V or greater difference between two values

Comment: R1,R2,R3 may be 3R0 i tried it worked

Comment: @Ch.SivaRamKishore I did not understand. Can you explain again?